# Lexicographical string ordering with buckets

Tags: python, string, sorting, suffix

I'm working on a genome and I want to sort a bunch of string by means of buckets. My strings are present is instances of a suffix class:

```
class Suffix:
    def __init__(self, index, suffix):
        self.index = index
        self.suffix = suffix
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'({self.index},{self.suffix})'
```

The suffix here is the string itself. First we sort them into different buckets according to their first string character:

```
buckets = [[] for x in range(6)]  # [[$],[A],[C],[G],[T],[N]]

# put every suffix into a bucket according to first character
for s in sa:
    if s.suffix[0] == '$':
        buckets[0].append(s)
    elif s.suffix[0] == 'A':
        buckets[1].append(s)
    elif s.suffix[0] == 'C':
        buckets[2].append(s)
    elif s.suffix[0] == 'G':
        buckets[3].append(s)
    elif s.suffix[0] == 'T':
        buckets[4].append(s)
    else:
        buckets[5].append(s)
```

Output:

```
[[],
 [(2,ACAATGCA$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$),
  (4,AATGCA$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$),
  (5,ATGCA$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$),
  (9,A$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$)],
 [(0,CGACAATGCA$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$),
  (3,CAATGCA$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$),
  (8,CA$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$)],
 [(1,GACAATGCA$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$),
  (7,GCA$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$)],
 [(6,TGCA$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$)],
 []]
```

And then I want to do recursion steps to return the sorted buckets for every bucket in buckets. I'm not being succesful however. Here is my full code:

```
def bucketsort(index,bucket):  # out of place sorting is not ideal
    sorted_bucket = [[] for x in range(6)]
    for s in bucket:
        if s.suffix[index] == '$':
            sorted_bucket[0].append(s)
        elif s.suffix[index] == 'A':
            sorted_bucket[1].append(s)
        elif s.suffix[index] == 'C':
            sorted_bucket[2].append(s)
        elif s.suffix[index] == 'G':
            sorted_bucket[3].append(s)
        elif s.suffix[index] == 'T':
            sorted_bucket[4].append(s)
        else:
            sorted_bucket[5].append(s)

    return sorted_bucket

def index_genome(genome):
    n = len(genome)
    genome = genome + 36*'$'  # to avoid going out of bounds
    # suffix array for whole genome
    sa = [Suffix(x,genome[x:]) for x in range(n)]
    
    buckets = [[] for x in range(6)]  # [[$],[A],[C],[G],[T],[N]]
    
    # put every suffix into a bucket according to first character
    for s in sa:
        if s.suffix[0] == '$':
            buckets[0].append(s)
        elif s.suffix[0] == 'A':
            buckets[1].append(s)
        elif s.suffix[0] == 'C':
            buckets[2].append(s)
        elif s.suffix[0] == 'G':
            buckets[3].append(s)
        elif s.suffix[0] == 'T':
            buckets[4].append(s)
        else:
            buckets[5].append(s)
            
    for index in range(n):  # we want to sort on the first 36 letters    
        for bucket in buckets:
            # while len > 1 (this assumes there are no exact repeats
            # in sa bc the len is never the same)
            while len(bucket) > 1:
                bucket = bucketsort(index, bucket)
    
    return buckets
```

How do I recursively sort a string according to this bucket method? Is there an algorithm someone could point me to?

The problem I have is that, with each iteration, I sort my strings into more and more nested lists and then can no longer access these nested lists.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that was quite unclear. I edited it! Basically, my recursion step is not working and my buckets are not getting sorted past the first letter in the strings... I'm not sure how to fix this or what I'm doing wrong. The problem I have is that, with each iteration, I sort my strings into more and more nested lists and then can no longer access these nested lists.

Comment: without looking at the code in detail, what I can see is that, in index_genome(), you apply bucketsort to each bucket in buckets but do nothing with it, and simple return buckets unchanged. I suppose you meant to put the sorted buckets into a list and then return that list as the function output?